# Does mogrify copy images that fall through resize filter?

Tags: images, photos, imagemagick, mogrify

I want to run the following command:

```
mogrify -path /somepath -resize '1600x1600>' *
```

are Images, that don't exceed the size of 1600x1600 copied to /somepath? (I am asking, since they would fall Through the '1600x1600<' filter)

Greetings Niklas

P.S.: I am currently on my windows machine, so I can't try it out.

Comment: I'm not completely sure how being on Windows prevents you from trying it out. ImageMagick exists for Windows too.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test run on a 20x20 GIF I had lying about, and it resized the image and put it in the directory in question - so the answer would be "yes, after being resized".

Comment: The question was: is it resizes though the file did not match the filter e.g. was too small... what command did you run?

Comment: @niklasfi: I ran the command you originally posted, `mogrify -path /somepath -resize '1600x1600<' *`
 - where you used < instead of >. With >, then correct, it does not resize.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Finally on my Linux machine again. I ran

```
mogrify -resize '1600x1600>' -path /somewhere *
```

on a 100x100px Image. And in deed it copied the 100x100 image to /somewhere without resizing it. So the answer is. YES